# TestNG Report display Blank

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse

[image]

[image]

I have created testcases in eclipse. I am trying to run that using TestNG, it displays output in console for fail and pass testcases, but I have open emailable-report.html from the test-output folder, but it is blank. Please give me reason for why it  is display blank?

Comment: What code are you running? What code are you testing?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Report Suite" >
  <test name="Report Test">
   
      <classes>
      <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.AccountPage"/>   
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
i am running report.xml file which i have generate

Comment: Edit your question and append this to the description for better readability.

Comment: with referance of https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/configuring-reportng-with-testng-to-generate-html-reports this url i have try to generate report but it is not working

Comment: Hi can I see your testng.xml? Also undo step num 2 and check default listener. and also remove this lines from testng.xml <listeners>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
      <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
  </listeners> after that run your code and refresh project.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Report Suite" >
  <test name="Report Test">
   
      <classes>
      <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.AccountPage"/>
     <!-- <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.Register"/> --> 
     <!-- <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.LoginPage"/> -->  
      
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: It is not containing listeners. 2 ways. 1 .remove that whole tag OR 2. Check the Default listener. And run.

Comment: Sorry i can not understand what you are telling can you describe in detail?

Comment: See step num 2 in this link https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/configuring-reportng-with-testng-to-generate-html-reports

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49582/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your configuration link that provided in comment , There is step num 3 is missed.

Please update `testng.xml` to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; 

<suite name="Report Suite" >
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
</listeners>
    <test name="Report Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.AccountPage"/>
            <!-- <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.Register"/> -->
            <!-- <class name="com.sevenbits.diecast.LoginPage"/> -->
        </classes>
    </test>
    <!-- Test -->
</suite>
<!-- Suite -->
```

Now run project from `testng.xml` :

**Right click on `testng.xml` and run as TestNG.**

Please let me know If there is any query.